# Issue with Capturing New Members in aiogram Bot when "Hide Members" is Enabled

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I'm working on creating a welcome bot using the aiogram library to greet new members who join a group. However, I'm encountering an issue when the group has enabled the "Hide Members" setting. In this case, new members joining the group don't receive the standard "user joined the group" notification. As a result, the @dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS) method doesn't seem to capture these new members.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue? If so, how did you manage to handle the situation? Is there a way to detect new members joining a group even when the "Hide Members" setting is active?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to overcome this challenge. Thank you in advance for your help!

Best regards,

aiogram  Issue with Capturing New Members in aiogram Bot when "Hide Members" is Enabled

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I also experience this problem. An admin bot in a group stops receiving NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS notifications once Hide members option is turned on.

It seems not right since the bot is granted admin rights. It there any workaround?